# Go to (the) heaven

Tags: definite-article

> He could stay, and suffer with a failing body, or go to **heaven** and join his loving family on the other side of life.

There is one heaven, so shouldn't we use *the* with heaven?

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go%20to%20heaven%2Cgo%20to%20the%20heaven&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20heaven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20the%20heaven%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Comment: Some places names have "the" in front of them, some don't.  After all you don't say, "Let's go to **the** England," or, "**the** India".

Comment: agree with you, we don’t usually use articles with countries. and there known rules for these cases.

Comment: "Heaven" (and "Hell") can be formally considered as countries, as both have numerous ambassadors to our world  :)

Comment: Heaven is like school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **go to bed** when you are sleepy.

You **go to school** when you are a student.

Some believe you **go to heaven** when you die.

This form without an article refers to the behavior or action *as* behavior or action, i.e. in the abstract or "in general", rather than to a particular bed, school, or heaven, as the case would be with the definite article, **the**,  and rather than to no bed, school, or heaven in particular, but still to *some* bed, school, or heaven, as the case would be with the indefinite article **a**.

Answer (score 2):

No, because assuming the subject follows one of the Christian faiths (or any faith with a heaven really), the heaven* being referred to is Heaven, a specific place with a proper name.

It should be written:

> ...or go to Heaven and join his family...

*Heaven spoken of as a concept, as above, would take an article.

Answer (score -1):

A) "I went to **a park**."  **<==**  could mean any park

B) I went to **the park**."  **<==** maybe one of many parks, but we're supposed to know which one is meant from context or other reasons.

C) "I went to **the Department of Education**." **<==** one of many departments, and then we supply context to tell you which one

D) "I went to **Disneyland**." **<==** Proper Noun: only one in existence and it's called this (no "the" is used)

So which pattern would you use for "heaven" or "hell" ?   D). It was probably spelled with a capital 'H' originally.

Comment: And what do you mean by "originally"?

Comment: The challenge is that "the" is used in a lot of unique place names: "The Grand Canyon", "The Eiffel Tower", "The White House" etc.  You might think "the" is used with place names that contain non-specific objects like "canyon" or "tower", but then you get "Buckingham Palace", one of many English "palaces".  So I don't think there is any absolute rule for these kind of proper nouns (much as it would be nice)

Comment: sky, earth... look at the sky, The satellite slowly rotates as it circles the earth.

Comment: @Andrew True, but in each of your examples, there is a word modifying the noun, implying there are possibly more than just this one in existence but we mean **this** one.  Not so with "**heaven**" and this makes all the difference (Buckingham Palace is perhaps a special case, done to emphasize its singularity, to give it more awe).  However......   TRomano hit it right by pointing out we don't use "**the**" when referring to an abstract **concept**, because notions of one, two, or more wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @TRomano I meant the historical origins of that use of the word.  I assumed it has its origins in a religious context where I'm used to seeing it capitalized.  I'm trying to think of an example of "<adjective> <noun>" but so far it seems like that pattern should always have a preceding "the", barring special-case exceptions.

Comment: @StewC don't get me wrong, I would love it if English made sense all the time.  But for every "The Grand Canyon" there is a "Mount Everest".

Comment: True, we are looking for major patterns which are helpful as guides to learners rather than iron-clad rules.  And unfortunately, "Mount" is not an adjective, so "Mount Everest" isn't really a counter-example.

Answer (score -1):

In order not to sound stilted and still refer to multiple ideas of heaven, it is best to refer to the specific heaven in question. For example:

...the Christian heaven...

...the Pastafarian heaven...

or

...heaven for Christians...

...heaven for Pastafarians...